# undefined method `reverse' in Ruby on Rails - displaying data in a table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to show all the instances of the model 'Project' in a table, using the following code:

```
<table style="table-layout: fixed;">
  <% @projects.each.reverse do |project| %>
    <tr>        
        <td style="width: 10%;"><%=link_to project.owner.upcase,user_path(project.owner) %> </td>

        <td><%= link_to project.title,  project_path(project) %></td>
        <td style=""><%= project.comments.pluck(:body).last || project.descr %></td>
        <td><%= project.sdate.strftime('%d/%m/%y') %></td>

      <td><%= project.comments.pluck(:expdate).last.try(:strftime, '%d/%m/%Y') || project.edate.strftime('%d/%m/%y') %></td>

        <td>
            <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_project_path(project) %> <br>
            <%= link_to 'Delete', project_path(project), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
        </td>

    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

But I am getting this error:

**NoMethodError in Projects#index**

**undefined method `reverse` for `#<Enumerator:0x44bc9c8>`**

Can anyone tell what's wrong??

I've used a similar line elsewhere, and it worked fine:

```
<%= render @project.comments.reverse %>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try `@projects.reverse.each`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to reverse individual objects instead of the collection.

Do as Aswin said: `@projects.reverse.each` instead of `each` before `reverse`.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling the `reverse` method on the result of `each` (which is an `Enumerator`) whereas `reverse` is a method on `Enumerable`.  You need to reverse the collection/array first, before iterating over it with `each`.  Try this instead.

```
@projects.reverse.each do |project|
```